# How to pass 2 or more parameters from jsp page to jasper report

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

[image]

I have a search criteria as shown above and also a text field. Here i am using jasper reports. So i have created the parameters in ireport-5.6.0, its working fine in internal preview of ireport-5.6.0, but when i want to send the values that is selected from a jsp page to ireport and print the data in PDF. Its not working. Only for one parameter its working and it is not taking the other two values that are selected.Here are my jsp pages.

Purchase.jsp

```
<form action="view.jsp" method="post">
<select name="complan">
<option value="">Make a selection</option>
<option value="Company Name">Company Name</option>
<option value="Contact Person">Contact Person</option>
<option value="Phone Number">Phone Number</option>
</select>
<select name="category">
<option value=""> Make a selection </option>
<option value="company">company</option>
<option value="institution">institution</option>
<option value="hospital">hospital</option>
<option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="search"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

view.jsp

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function setAction(nPage){

            document.forms[0].action = nPage;
        }
    </script>
<form>
<% 
String search=request.getParameter("search");
session.setAttribute("sea",search);
String category=request.getParameter("category");
session.setAttribute("cat",category);
String complan = request.getParameter("complan");
session.setAttribute("com",complan);
%>
<select onchange="setAction(this.value)">
<option value=''> Make a selection </option>
<option value='PDF_LEAD.jsp'> PDF</option>
<option value='XLS_LEAD.jsp'> XLS </option>
<option value='DOC_LEAD.jsp'> DOC </option>
<option value='XLSX_LEAD.jsp'> XLSX </option>
</select>
<br/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PDF_LEAD.jsp

```
<body>
<% 
Connection conn = null;
String sear=(String)session.getAttribute("sea");
String cate=(String)session.getAttribute("cat");
String comp=(String)session.getAttribute("com");
try 
{ 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_database","root","root");
    String jrxmlFile ="D:/dev/tools/jasper files/report10.jrxml";
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

    System.out.println("Compiling Report Designs");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    System.out.println("Creating JasperPrint Object");
    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("complan",comp);
    parameters.put("search",sear);
    parameters.put("category",cate);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,conn);
    byte bytes[] = new byte[10000]; 
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    ByteArrayOutputStream PDFStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint); 
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, PDFStream); 
    exporter.exportReport(); 
    System.out.println("Size of byte array:"+PDFStream.size()); 
    bytes = PDFStream.toByteArray(); 
    response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 1"); 
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 2"); 
    PDFStream.close(); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 3"); 

    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream(); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 4"); 
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length); 
    outputStream.flush(); 
    outputStream.close(); 

}
catch(Exception e) 
{e.printStackTrace();} 

%>
</body>
```

Comment: You are using the correct way to pass parameters, I think the problem is in the .jrxml (or that you call the parameters in different way), I need to see the first part of the jrxml file. Furthermore to be sure that you code works before setting parameters try outputing the values of sear, cate and comp.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Do you have any example report in which 2 or more parameters are passed and report is generated ??

Comment: Sure,a life full of examples, My magic ball is telling my that you are using them in the sql and maybe you should try to $P!{PARAM} instead of $P{PARAM} note the !

Comment: Not working what do intend? not compiling anything or you just don't see the parameters?

Comment: @PetterFriberg I just dont see the parameters. For example when i select "Company Name" and "Company" and i write "Google" in text box and press "search" it goes to "view.jsp" there i will select"PDF_LEAD.jsp and "submit" it is showing a blank PDF page.Yeah i put"$P!{PARAM}" in sql query

Comment: If you have any working report with parameters then you mail me.This is my Email    "samueljohnhappy@gmail.com". Thanking You

Comment: Trust me there is nothing strange with multiple parameters in report <parameter name="DESTINAZIONE" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <parameter name="ID_USCITA_CLIENTE" class="java.lang.Integer">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Integer(1)]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="BARCODE" class="java.lang.String">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Test"]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter> this is from one of my reports...

Comment: Include your jrxml in the question and I will check it.

Comment: @PetterFriberg                                    <parameter name="category" class="java.lang.String">
  <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{Category}]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="search" class="java.lang.String">
  <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{Company_Name}]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
 <queryString>
  <![CDATA[select * from lead where category =$P!{category} and Company_Name=$P!{search}]]>
 </queryString>

Comment: Remove the defaultValueExpression you can't use the fields here, the default is used when you don't pass any data on parameter, but should be in your case a String es "google" so you can test the report.. Basically the defualt you can use to check that queris works and if parameters arrive

Comment: The other problem that I see is that if you use =$P!{category}  the ! you need to single quote your query ='$P!{category}' if you use $P{category} not since it use prepardstatement

Comment: @PetterFriberg When i removed the default value expression its showing "Compilation Running Time 234"

Comment: This works: <parameter name="DESTINAZIONE" class="java.lang.String"/>, check you xml, if you can't make it work leave just a String in default expression as in my example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92047/discussion-between-petter-friberg-and-chitti-oneterahertz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i have to thank @Peter Friberg,because without you it wont be possible. I removed "default value expression" in jrxml. That is as follows.

```
<parameter name="category" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="search" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from lead where category ='$P!{category}' and Company_Name like '$P!{search}%']]>
    </queryString>
```

My SQL query is

```
select * from lead where category ='$P!{category}' and Company_Name like '$P!{search}%'
```

Comment: Great that you answered it (upvote), just close it to ; )

Comment: Futhermore when you are a bit further into you testing it would be better to  not use $P!{ since if es company is passed as goo'g your code will break. The solution is using without !, $P{, you force jasper report to use prepared statement the query would be something like this select * from lead where category =$P{category} and Company_Name like $P{search}, note the % you need to add in jsp  before passing it to jasper report